# How can I send a file with the DNS protocol?

Tags: c#, sockets, dns

**How can I send a file with the DNS protocol in C#?**  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, not practical so.

Since DNS requests include easy to manipulate text part squeezing file via  DNS requests is just matter of slicing data into small enough chunks and sending requests to your own DNS server that knows how to extract data. For example sending Base64 data as part of sub-domain.

Tools:

- Read specification or at least some details of the [DNS protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd197470(v=ws.10).aspx)
- C# [DNS class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns(v=vs.110).aspx).
- custom DNS server for your own domain.
- configure DNS record for all sub-domain pointing to same server

Steps:

- Slice file into small chunks and encode each into url-safe Base64 or Base32/Base16 strings. Send DNS request to your server with chunk as sub-domain name. Possibly include chunk index along the data.
- The server should extract sub-domain and put back into a file.

Sample exchange for file consisting of `[04 00 00 08 00 00]` bytes encoded into 2 chunks `"BAAA", "CAAA"` :

- client sends resolve BAAA.mydomain.com
- DNS server receives request takes `BAAA` part and put into a file (after decoding)
- DNS server responds with some IP (does not matter what)
- client recieves and ignores response
- client sends resolve CAAA.mydomain.com
- DNS server receives request takes `CAAA` part and put appends it to the file (after decoding)
- DNS server responds with some IP (does not matter what)
- client recieves and ignores response